# Matching Simulated Moments Perfectly in Practice

Tags: econometrics, simulation, identifiability, method-of-moments

Several sources suggest that when estimating a model using the simulated method of moments (SMM), one ought to always be able to get the difference between the empirical and simulated moments to be 0 on average when the number of moments (P) and the number of parameters (D) are equal. In my experience, I have found this to rarely be true. Am I misunderstanding SMM or is it implied when making these kinds of statements that this will only be *unambiguously* true when the model is correctly specified? I am beating my head against the wall trying (and failing) to match every moment *exactly* (in the P = D case) because it feels like I ought to be able to.

https://www.jasondebacker.com/classes/Lecture10_Notes_SMM.pdf and [http://www.columbia.edu/~sn2294/papers/abc.pdf](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Esn2294/papers/abc.pdf) and https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/jalali/files/msm_book_chapter.pdf